# Re-associate another IP to a running instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a complicated use case for this , 
But for short , while an instance is running, can I switch the elastic IP to another one ? and what will happen in this time interval (between de-associating , and re-associating [might be 10-30 minutes] ) .. Won't it be able to communicate over the internet ?

**EDIT:**
Great answers so far, but this answers the second part of the question, the main one is , how to change the IP while it is running?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of your questions are more or less addressed in the [Feature Guide: Amazon EC2 Elastic IP Addresses](http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1346), e.g:

- *While an instance is running, can I switch the elastic IP to another one?*
  Of course, that's one of the main use cases for Elastic IP addresses:
  *Unlike a standard EC2 Public IP Address, Elastic IP Addresses are allocated to accounts and can be remapped to other instances when
  desired. [This includes running instances, see "How to change the Elastic IP Address of a running EC2 instance" below.]*
- *What will happen in this time interval (between de-associating, and re-associating [might be 10-30 minutes])?*
  That'd be longer than advertized, see the FAQ *How long
  does it take to remap an Elastic IP address?*:

  > In most cases, this
  >   will typically take less than a few minutes from when you instruct us
  >   to remap the Elastic IP, and we are continuing to work to make this
  >   even faster. *[I've actually not experienced this process taking
  >   longer than a minute myself]*
- *Won't it be able to communicate over the internet?*
    That depends on the scenario at hand, but as a simplification you should probably work with this assumption, as per the following two FAQs:

  - *If an Elastic IP is removed from an instance is the instance reachable from the internet?*

    > Removing the Elastic IP from an instance temporarily leaves the
    >   instance without a Public IP Address. A background process in the
    >   cloud will re-assign a new Public IP to the instance after a short
    >   period of time. The instance will remain reachable from within the
    >   cloud on its private IP address during this process.
  - *Why do existing connections still work after I associate a new IP address to an instance?*

    > When you remap an Elastic IP to an instance, some of your preexisting
    >   communications (to the old and now unmapped IP address) will continue
    >   to work even after the remap. For example, if you have an open ssh
    >   connection to an instance via its system assigned Public IP address
    >   and subsequently associate one of your Elastic IP addresses with that
    >   instance, the ssh session might continue to function normally for
    >   some time. This behavior is expected but unreliable. We strongly urge
    >   you to reestablish connections via the new remapped IP addresses to
    >   ensure that your software functions correctly.

#### How to change the Elastic IP Address of a running EC2 instance

The answer to your follow up question is embedded/implied in the aforementioned guide as well, but addressed in more detail in chapter [Elastic IP Addresses (EIP)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-ip-addresses-eip.html), specifically in sections [Associating an Elastic IP Address with a Running Instance in Amazon EC2](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-ip-addresses-eip.html#using-instance-addressing-eips-associating) and [Associating an Elastic IP Address with a Different Running Instance in Amazon EC2](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-ip-addresses-eip.html#using-instance-addressing-eips-associating-different):

- Basically this is performed via the EC2 API action [AssociateAddress](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/ApiReference-query-AssociateAddress.html), which is facilitated by either the [AWS Management Console](http://aws.amazon.com/console/) or the [Amazon EC2 API Tools](http://aws.amazon.com/developertools/351) in turn (specifically [ec2-associate-address](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/CommandLineReference/ApiReference-cmd-AssociateAddress.html)), as outlined in the aforementioned sections.

Please refer to the EC2 [IP Information FAQ](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/IP_Information.html) for even more details regarding the subject matter.

Answer (score 1):

Elastic IPs are assigned using NAT. Your instance has an internal IP that is NATed to the Elastic IP. While an instance has no Elastic IP associated it will have an arbitrary IP from a pool and thus will still be able to communicate with the internet (given that access rules are properly configured).

Comment: Switching the IP is what is most important to me now .. :) Do u have a clue?

Answer (score 1):

I created this bash script to change the public ip (eip) of a running instance in a VPC. You just provide the name you gave that instance (TAG Name="") so it will convert the Name Tag into the instance ID. Changing your public DNS will always take time. Changing the EIP address in the aws gui is annoying. Dissasociate old ip, Get New IP, Associate New IP, Release Old IP. Mouse clicks stink.

```
#change vpc instance public IP address (EIP -> NIC|INSTANCE)
#usage "changeip [instance friendly tag=Name] [region]"
#example "changeip my.instnace us-west-1"
#dafault region is us-west-1 (you must include --region for $region default)
#for VPC instances only
function changeip {
    if [[ ! $1 ]]; then
        echo 'Error : You must provide tag name for instance'
        echo 'Example:  changeip [friendly name]'
        return
    fi
    if [[ $2 ]]; then
        region='--region '$2
        echo 'Using region '$2
    else
        region='--region us-west-1' #sets default region
        echo 'Using default '$region
    fi  
    name=$1
    instance=$(ec2-describe-instances $region | grep Name | grep $name | cut -f3)
    if [[ ! $instance =~ ^('i-'[A-Za-z0-9]*)$ ]]; then
        echo 'Error : Getting the instance id'
        echo $instance
        return
    fi
    echo 'Applying to '$1 '=> '$instance
    echo 'Please wait....'
    ip_new=$(ec2-allocate-address $region -d vpc | cut -f2)
    if [[ ! $ip_new =~ ^[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}$ ]]; then
        echo 'Error : Getting a new IP address'
        echo $ip_new
        return
    fi
    new_idas=$(ec2-describe-addresses $region $ip_new | cut -f 5) >> /dev/null
    if [[ ! $new_idas =~ ^('eipalloc-'[A-Za-z0-9]*)$ ]]; then
        echo 'Error : Getting New IP allocation id eipalloc'
        echo $new_idas
        return  
    fi
    ip_old=$(ec2-describe-addresses $region | grep $instance | cut -f2)
    if [[ ! $ip_old =~ ^[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}$ ]]; then
        echo 'Error : Getting old IP address'
        echo $ip_old
        return
    fi
    id_dis=$(ec2-describe-addresses $region $ip_old | cut -f 6)
    if [[ ! $id_dis  =~ ^('eipassoc-'[A-Za-z0-9]*)$ ]]; then
        echo 'Error : Dissasociating Old IP'
        echo $id_dis
        return
    fi
    id_release=$(ec2-describe-addresses $region $ip_old | cut -f 5) >> /dev/null
    if [[ ! $new_idas =~ ^('eipalloc-'[A-Za-z0-9]*)$ ]]; then
        echo 'Error : Release Old IP'
        echo $id_release
        return
    fi
    ec2-disassociate-address $region -a $id_dis  >> /dev/null
    sleep 8
    ec2-release-address $region -a $id_release >> /dev/null
    ec2-associate-address $region -i $instance -a $new_idas >> /dev/null
    echo 'SUCCESS!'
    echo 'Old = '$ip_old
    echo 'New = '$ip_new
}
```

Comment: O yah and this only applies to a vpc instance. Regular instances need to be rebooted to obtain another EIP.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use Public DNS name to access the system.
No problem to communicate over internet.

do a curl from the instance to know private / public addresses to use

http : // 169 . 254. 169. 254/latest/meta-data/local-ipv4

http : // 169. 254. 169. 254/latest/meta-data/public-ipv4

Refer : http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AESDG-chapter-instancedata.html

Comment: but do you know how to change the IP while the instance is running?

Comment: you can use a elastic ip address for a running instance

Answer (score 0):

Yes: you can change the IP address of a running instance. Just associate a second elastic IP address with the instance and it will replace the existing one.